# How often should I use sentence connectors in a paragraph?

Tags: grammar-identification, style

I have this exercise in my Grammar book:

> Schreiben Sie den Text neu und verbinden Sie dabei die Sätze mit Konnektoren. Denken Sie daran: Sie müssen auch den Satzbau verändern
>
> China wird als Wirtschaftspartner und als Reiselander immer wichtiger. Viele Menschen wollen die chinesische Sprache erlernen. Für Kinder gibt es in Mainz ein Angebot Chinesisch lesen, schreiben und sprechen zu lernen. Die chinesische Schule Mainz wurde gegründet. Der Unterricht findet jeden Samstagvormittag statt.
>
> Die Lehrer sind größenteils chinesische Akademiker. Sie sind aus China nach Deutschland gekommen. Es gibt leider keine kindgerechten Schulbücher für Chinesisch in Deutschland. Die Lehrer müssen die Unterrichtsmaterialien selbst entwickeln. Das Erlernen der Schriftzeichen braucht viel Geduld. Es wird auch Kalligrafie unterrichtet. Die Sprache wird unterrichtet . Es wird auch die chinesische Kultur unterrichtet. Sprache und Kultur gehören zussamen, meint der Schulleiter.

We were taught these connectors:

1. Konsekutiv: folglich, infolgedessen,demnach, insofern
2. Konsekutiv( Negativ Folge):andernfalls,sonst
3. Konditionale: Ausser wen(HS+NS), es sei denn (HS+HS)

Now, I have what is perhaps a dumb question, for every consecutive sentence could be chained with a consecutive connector. So, the question is, how often should I chain it?

Comment: This is a question of style. Thus, there is no general answer. I don't believe this is fundamentally different when writing in English.

Comment: I think the main point is to be familiar with the meanings and to be able to figure out which one to use if you do decide it's appropriate. So for the purposes of the exercise I'd just assume you're meant to use them every time. In general though, I agree with the the previous comment; it's a stylistic choice.

Comment: Do it as long as you find it easy to understand....